# About the necessity of having a service

Tags: android, service, background, back

Well, i'm developing an android application that will hold an IRC client. At first i thought the correct was develop the client under a service, but it is giving me a considerable work cause i dont have so much exp on android and almost no one with services.
Im having problems on service/activity/fragment lifecycles (im using all) and especially  bind/unbind service, cause i need to retrieve all conversations that still running with service and receiving messages, and maybe the critical point, i yet dont have ideia how to maintain these conversations receiving messages, almost always cause the components sometimes needs a context and i cannot call getactivity while the service is alone.
Now, the question is: some time ago i made and app that reproduces a web radio station, without service. The activity simply plays the player and, if user press back button, i overrided:

```
      @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {
           if (!playerStarted) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(homeIntent);
    }
}
```

And this way, when user press back button, the device go to home and the activity still playing background, like a service would. When the user click on app icon again, the OS just put the activity on top again, and it is the same.
Its seems easier to me than all complexity of start/bind a service and the care of retrieve all data;
So, finally, my questions are: What happens if a develop my irc client just sending home instead of let a running service? What is the really need of a service in my project?

Answer (score 0):

A service is (extends) Context. Both your Radio and IRC client apps are prime candidates for using a service.

Comment: I guess the true is im a fool kkkk.
How (where) can i get some help about structuring my project with service? I need the msgs to be added in a list when they received even without activity. I tried to made fragments that still running on service and in onbind() i get them from service, but doesnot work...

Comment: I don't know the IRC protocol well, but I imagine you will want the service to keep an open socket to an IRC server to receive the messages, and keep them either in a list in memory, or (for higher durability and smaller memory footprint) store them in a database. To serve the messages to the client you can either implement a method in your server interface (which you bind from client) that returns the list of messages. Or in the second case, implement a content provider, and a cursor loader in the client.

Comment: Is by this way. The PircBotX give me a listener interface with methods for wich event that it gets. My problems actually are on bind/unbind lifecycles and how to maintain the messages being stored while service is running in background and retain this messages when activity is bounded.